# Instance not storing value

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, xcode, instance

I have three classes involved in this problem:

1. my appDelegate
2. my data class
3. my my viewcontroller class

when my app launches I use the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method in my app delegate to create an instance of the data class and then call the queryMessagesFromBackend method to fill my messages array.

Then in my view controller I create another instance of my data class to access the messages array (dataClass.messages) that i just filled, however its empty.  This does not make sense because when the method is called it Logs all the data the messages array has. Why is my new instance showing that the messages array is empty?

I would provide code but that seems useless

Comment: You expect the `messages` array in two separate instances of the data class to be the same?

Comment: yeah i did.  Im guessing thats the wrong approach

Comment: your array is an ivar from your data class? Best way to share this instance between controller would be to use a singleton

Answer (score 0):

1. In yours "app delegate" make first "data class" object an ivar (or property) of "app delegate"
2. Declare some getter for that data object in app delegate class.
3. In your's view controller - get app delegate via shared NSApp instance.
4. Get shared data object from app delegate with introduced getter.

---

Tip: U can use an interface (protocol) for making things little cleaner:

```
@protocol XYZDataProvider <NSObject>
- (XYZDataClass *) data;
@end

...

@interface XYZAppDelegate : NSAppDelegate <XYZDataProvider> {
    XYZDataClass *data;
}

@end

...

@implementation XYZAppDelegate

// either can init data in didFinishBlahBlahBlah...

- (void) did ... {
    self->data = [XYZDataClass new];
    ...
}

// implement protocol's required method
- (XYZDataClass *) data {
    /// and then return on request...
    return self->data;

    // or do so-caled lazy-loading:

    // if (!self->data) {
    //     $self->data = [... ..];
    //     ...
    // }
    // return self->data;
}

@end

...

@implementation XYZViewController

- (void) processData {
    NSAppDelegate *appDelegate = [NSApp delegate];
    if ([appDelegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(XYZDataProvider)]) {
        XYZDataClass *data = [(id<XYZDataProvider>)appDelegate data];

        // do smth with data
        ...

    }

    ...    
}

@end
```

*Note: code contains errors (written directly in browser...)*